# Set html element value from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

Hi i'm developing a webserver with nodejs on backend. Once you access the site after logging in, you access a configuration screen for some data. This is the part of nodejs that takes care of accessing the page:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    if(sess.username){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/portal.html'));
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }

 });
```

I need access to this page through app.get because in other areas of the code I use the url to send error messages to the same page by reloading it, but I would like to have a way to be able to fill in all the html fields when the page loads.

All the data that I should enter are enclosed in a JSON file which I can access from the nodejs backend but not from the front end.

Any ideas on how to fix this without sending plaintext data in the URL?

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of templating engine to render your html before responding with it. Some popular templating engines are: [`EJS`](https://ejs.co/), [`Handlebars`](https://handlebarsjs.com/), and [`Jade`](http://jade-lang.com/) to name a few.. These templating engines allow you to inject variables into HTML.

Comment: Correct Matt, the portal.html should be a template which can be used to populate data before sending the page to front end.  All of the above engines, I have tried and found working perfectly.  FDC, go for one of them.  

Comment: @MattOestreich Thanks i try EJS and it works great!